# For a field $K$ is $K\subset{K[X_{1},...X_{n}]}$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $K$ be any field and $K[X_1,...X_n]$ the ring of polynomials in  $X_1,...X_n$ with coefficients in $K$. I am wondering if $K$ is a subset of $K[X_1,...X_n]$. I believe $K\subset{K[X_1]}$ since each scalar $a\in{K}$ can be associated to the constant polynomial $c(X)=a$ but my intuition tells me it doesn't hold when there are $n$ indeterminates $X_1,...X_n$ any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $\;K\;$ can be embedded in the polynomials ring, and though *formally* it is not  a subset of it we usually consider it so under the embedding you mention.

Comment: @Timbuc Since $K$ is not a formal subset I assume $K$ can't be considered an ideal of $K[X_1,...X_n]$ ?

Comment: $K$ is not ideal because it contains unit of the ring (under embedding). Element identity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @ChristianLaPointe I don't know what "normal subset" is, and also read the other comment by user... : if it were an ideal then it'd be the whole ring, which is false.

Comment: @user52045 $K$ is an ideal iff $n = 0$. An ideal can contain $1$, namely the ideal $(1)  = R$ (the whole ring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a set (for example $S=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$) and $A$ a ring, the polynomial ring $A[S]$  (more usually written $A[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ if $S=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$) can be defined as a ring $B$ together with a ring homomorphism $\iota\colon A\to B$ as well as a map $i\colon S\to B$ such that for any other ring $C$ and ring homomoprhism $\phi\colon A\to C$ and map $f\colon S\to C$, there exists one and only one ring homomorphism $h\colon B\to C$ with $h\circ \iota=\phi$ and $h\circ i=f$.

As usual with universal objects, this definition is only *up to canonical isomorphism* and among the various isomorphic choices none needs to be preferred. Especially, since $\iota$ turns out to necessarily be an embedding, it is *common* to simply identify $A$ with $\iota(A)$ and hence consider $A$ a subring of $A[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. (Likewise, $i$ turns out to be injective and we therefore *commonly* consider $S$ a subset of $A[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$).